# Making `routerLinkActive` active for two different components

Tags: angular

In Angular 2+, if I have a navbar like so set up in an 'Articles' feature module:

```
    <li>
      <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="current">Current</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="future">Future</a>
    </li>
```

Then when I navigate to /articles/current or /articles/future then the correct routerLinkActive class is set.

How can I set the routerlinkActive to my "Future" link if the url is /articles/article-slug?

Ie; I'd like the text 'Future' to appear with the class 'active' even though I'm in article-slug (which is the DetailHomeComponent)

I haven't shown the CurrentComponent, but it contains a list of items with routes like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/articles', article.slug]">
```

These are my routes:

```
    path: '', 
    component: MenuComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '', redirectTo: 'current',  pathMatch: "full" 
        },
        {
            path: 'current', component: CurrentComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'future', component: FutureComponent,
        },
        {
            path: ':slug', 
            component: DetailHomeComponent,        
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Where do you have your route for `article-slug`? And, if I get what you are asking, is it how to make the text "Future" appear with the class "active" even though you are not navigating to the path `future` but `article-slug`?

Comment: Question is unclear, what you want to achieve? provide a fiddle/plunker links as well.

Comment: That's correct, I'd like the text 'Future' to appear with the class 'active' even through i'm in artticle-slug (which is the DetailHomeComponent)

Comment: If it was easy, I wouldn't have asked the question

Comment: you can use a ngClass to add the class 'active'  depend on a variable set with subscribing to route and checking current activated route

Comment: I've updated the question to take into account comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ngClass and subscribing to the activated route and setting a variable for required route we can achieve this.

```
<li>
<a routerLinkActive="active"
[ngClass]= "{'active': enableFuture}"
routerLink="future">Future</a>
</li>
```

In TS:-

```
enableFuture: false;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
 ngOnInit() {
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    if(params['slug']){
     this.enableFuture = true;
    }else{
     this.enableFuture = false;
    }
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<li>
  <a routerLink="future"
     [ngClass]="{'active': myService.enableFutureLink}">
     Future
  </a>
</li>
```

And in both `DetailHomeComponent` and `FutureComponent`:

```
constructor(private myService: MyService) {
    myService.enableFutureLink = true;
}
```

Where MyService is some service you can use to communicate both components. As an alternative you can use the Router to know the currently activated route.

Comment: I think this.enableFuturelink will not be available in parent Component